# EntityFramework cascading update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, cascade

Coming from an NHibernate background - I have some auditing columns to reflect who last edited a record, and when that edit occurred.

I've overridden SaveChanges to look for a common base class, and update anything with EntityState.Modified/Added and set these values --

However, I want to cascade updates from child to parent in some cases, so that when I edit child, the audit tracking fields of Parent are also updated.

Does EntityFramework support this in any way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm going to add an a custom attribute on the parents I want to cascade - and then when I detect a modified entity, find the properties with that attribute and update those as well.